# changing code from js to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have really lack of time to learn as much of jQuery as I can. I wrote function which blocks subit and prints error, when password is too short:

```
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var registerButton = document.getElementById('registerButton');
var text = document.getElementById('passwordStrengthText');
var value = password.value;
if (value === "") {
    registerButton.disabled = true;
}

password.addEventListener('input', function () {
    var value = password.val();
    if (value.length < 4 || value === "") {
        text.innerHTML = "(Too Short)";
        registerButton.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        text.innerHTML = "";
        registerButton.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

jQuery:

```
var password = $('#password');
var registerButton = $('#registerButton');
var text = $('#passwordStrengthText');
var value = password.val();
if (value === "") {
    registerButton.disabled = true;
}

password.addEventListener('input', function () {
    var value = password.val();
    if (value.length < 4 || value === "") {
        text.innerHTML = "(Too Short)";
        registerButton.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        text.innerHTML = "";
        registerButton.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

This code is in file passwordStrength.js, which is included to my html file after bootstrap jquery includes. Can some1 explain why doesn't it work? First version works just like I want.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quite a lot of things in your jQuery version.

First of all, to set the `disabled` attribute of an element in jQuery, use `.prop('disabled',true);`.

Then, to set the HTML of an element, use `.html("...");`

In jQuery, you can also stop using `addEventListener` and use `.on()` instead.

*Here is a working version of your code :*

```js
let password = $('#password');
let registerButton = $('#registerButton');
let text = $('#passwordStrengthText');
let value = password.val();
if (value === "") {
    registerButton.prop('disabled',true);
}

password.on('input', function () {
    let value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length < 4 || value === "") {
        text.html("(Too Short)");
        registerButton.prop('disabled',true);
    }
    else {
        text.html("");
        registerButton.prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password" />
<button id="registerButton">Register</button>
<p id="passwordStrengthText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to execute native js commands on jQuery-Objects here, you need to use the corresponding jQuery-Syntax:

```
var password = $('#password');
var registerButton = $('#registerButton');
var text = $('#passwordStrengthText');
var value = password.val();
if (value === "") {
    registerButton.attr('disabled', true);
}

password.on('input', function () {
    var value = password.val();
    if (value.length < 4 || value === "") {
        text.html("(Too Short)");
        registerButton.attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        text.html("");
        registerButton.attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

An other way would be to get the native HTML-Elements form the jQuery-Objects by `[0]` or `.get(0)` but if you do this, you could just use nativ js not jQuery